# is there a method to select longest string from list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

i have a list like :

```
[{'name': 'NOUN-NOUN', 'start_char': 91, 'end_char': 105, 'lemma': 'digital groupe', 'text': 'digital groupe'} ,
{'name': 'NOUN', 'start_char': 91, 'end_char': 98, 'lemma': 'digital', 'text': 'digital'}
{'name': 'NOUN', 'start_char': 99, 'end_char': 105, 'lemma': 'groupe', 'text': 'groupe'}
{'name': 'NOUN-PROPN', 'start_char': 99, 'end_char': 113, 'lemma': 'groupe siparex', 'text': 'groupe siparex'}
{'name': 'NOUN-NOUN-PROPN', 'start_char': 91, 'end_char': 113, 'lemma': 'digital groupe siparex', 'text': 'digital groupe siparex'}

{'name': 'PROPN-PROPN', 'start_char': 0, 'end_char': 12, 'lemma': 'Jean François', 'text': 'Jean François'}
    ]
```

i want to clean this list and get only the longest string based on start and end char (so remove the others from the list) :
so i want to have in output :

```
   [{'name': 'NOUN-NOUN-PROPN', 'start_char': 91, 'end_char': 113, 'lemma': 'digital groupe siparex', 'text': 'digital groupe siparex'},
{'name': 'PROPN-PROPN', 'start_char': 0, 'end_char': 12, 'lemma': 'Jean François', 'text': 'Jean François'}]
```

thank you

Comment: Since you tagged spaCy, maybe you want the `filter_spans` function? https://spacy.io/api/top-level/#util.filter_spans

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
lst = [{'name': 'NOUN-NOUN', 'start_char': 91, 'end_char': 105, 'lemma': 'digital groupe', 'text': 'digital groupe'} ,
{'name': 'NOUN', 'start_char': 91, 'end_char': 98, 'lemma': 'digital', 'text': 'digital'},
{'name': 'NOUN', 'start_char': 99, 'end_char': 105, 'lemma': 'groupe', 'text': 'groupe'},
{'name': 'NOUN-PROPN', 'start_char': 99, 'end_char': 113, 'lemma': 'groupe siparex', 'text': 'groupe siparex'},
{'name': 'NOUN-NOUN-PROPN', 'start_char': 91, 'end_char': 113, 'lemma': 'digital groupe siparex', 'text': 'digital groupe siparex'}
]

print(max(lst, key=lambda e:e['end_char'] - e['start_char']))
```

Comment: Shouldn't the metric be `end_char - start_char` (to get the length of the string)?

Comment: @AKK Sorry I misread the question. But now solved.

Comment: i EDIT my post , because in the same list we can have many words ... 
so in the output we can have many words ...

Comment: i want to get the longest string only for strings which share the same start or end index

Answer (score 0):

In light of your updated post, you could try something like:

```
  lengths = [d['end_char'] - d['start_char'] for d in data ]                      
  print([obj for obj in data if obj["end_char"] - obj["start_char"] == max(lengths)] )
```

It's not as concise as the first answer, but will return multiple words.